# How can I observe the "voltage dips" the starter kit talks about in Project 5?

Tags: arduino-uno

Project 5 of the Arduino Starter Kit [book](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/IN1060/v21/arduino/arduino-projects-book.pdf) (page 63) involves wiring up a potentiometer to control a servomotor (see diagram). The book also recommends wiring up decoupling capacitors as shown in the diagram:

> When a servo motor starts to move, it draws more current than if it were already in motion. This will cause a dip in the voltage on your board. By placing a 100uf capacitor across power and ground right next to the male headers as shown in Fig. 1, you can smooth out any voltage changes that may occur. You can also place a capacitor across the power and ground going into your potentiometer.

Since the book doesn't explicitly warn against it, I decided to do this whole project without the capacitors just to see what would happen. It seemed to work fine, I didn't notice any erratic behavior. Is there some experiment I could do to actually measure these voltage "dips"?

I thought maybe I could try to measure the voltage drop across the servo, so I wired it in series with a resistor and connected the A0 ADC pin between the servo and the resistor. I did measure a drop, but the servo didn't work... I'm guessing it wasn't getting enough power because of the resistor?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing it wasn't getting enough power because of the resistor?

Yes, that is probably what happened (you didn't specify what value your resistor had). When the servo tries to draw more current, more current has to flow through the resistor. This means more voltage over the resistor and less for the servo, which then doesn't have enough to to powerful or even run at all (depending on the resistors value).

> Is there some experiment I could do to actually measure these voltage "dips"?

You tried to measure the dips with the Arduino. Since the servo is connected directly to the 5V line of the Arduino, so its own Vcc, you cannot measure it the same way as the potentiometer. By default `analogRead()` uses Vcc as reference, meaning the max value. Instead you can configure it to use the internal 1.1V fixed reference (which doesn't depend on Vcc)(refer to [`analogReference()`](https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogreference/)) and divide down Vcc with a fixed voltage divider (so that the voltage on the analog input pin would not exceed 1.1V).

Though to see the dips you still would need to measure the data points fast enough to catch them. Without knowing how long the dips might be it is difficult to say, if you can easily catch them. There are ways to do analog measurements relatively fast, but for a beginner (and specifically for a beginner book) that is a bit much.

The easier, but also more expensive solution (in terms of tools) is to measure Vcc with an oscilloscope. As entry a USB oscilloscope might be fitting (in the range of maybe 50$). If you don't wanna buy, you might be able to get access to one at the next makerspace or university. Some schools also might have some oscilloscopes.

> Since the book doesn't explicitly warn against it, I decided to do this whole project without the capacitors just to see what would happen. It seemed to work fine

Dips in your supplied voltage might cause the Arduino to reset. But that only happens, when the dip is too big. And that depends on multiple factors:

- How much current can be drawn from your power supply. USB ports on a PC won't give you more than 500mA for example. And some battery types have a big series resistance, meaning that the voltage will drop significantly, when you draw too much current from them.
- Sometimes, when working on a breadboard, the contacts might also have a significant resistance to them. This can lead to a voltage loss there.
- How strong the motor is. In starter kits you typically have these cheap and small SG90 micro servos. These don't draw a lot of power generally and are not really strong.
- How much load is on the motor. A motor draws different amounts of current depending on its load. When it runs feely the currently is the smallest. When its starting, then it needs to fight against its own inertia, thus needing more current. The most current is used, when the motor stalls, because it is not powerful enough to push against the load.

The last two points affect the motor current, which might cause a voltage dip, if the power supply cannot provide that much current with the specified voltage.

The capacitors are a precaution in this case. I think the author wanted to explain this to make sure that it would work for everyone and that students would already know about this, when moving to bigger, more power hungry projects.

Comment: I tried a 10k resistor and a 220 ohm - with the former the servo didn't budge, with the latter it kind of twitched slowly.